# Two fundamental questions about convexity of a function (number1)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

The first question is as follows (see the [second one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207432/two-fundamental-questions-about-convexity-of-a-function-number2)):

> If $f$ is a convex function it is know that there is at most a single minimum. However the argument of the minimum is not guaranteed to be unique. For example $f(x)=c$ is a constant function, therefore it is convex and also concave. Its minimum (also maximum) is $c$. But the whole domain of $f$ is a solution to $\arg \min_x f(x)$. Then the obviious question is: what are the sufficient conditions such that  $\arg \min_x f(x)$ of a convex function $f$ is unique?

My guess is that $f$ must be strictly convex but I dont have any proof.

Comment: @goblin okay then let me do it.

Comment: A very minor English-language nitpick: strict convexity is *a* sufficient condition. It is certainly not the *only* sufficient condition.

Comment: @MichaelGrant for example?

Comment: An answer is being constructed. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.

**Definition 0.** By the *minimizer* of a function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, I mean the set of all $x \in X$ such that for all $x' \in X$, we have $f(x) \leq f(x')$.

> **Proposition 0.** Suppose $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly convex, where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set. Then the
>   minimizer of $f$ has at most one element.

*Proof.* Suppose $x$ and $y$ are elements of the minimizer of $f$. I claim that $x=y$.

For a contradiction, suppose $x \neq y$.

**Idea.** Use strict convexity to find a point between $x$ and $y$ at which $f$ is strictly less than $f(x)$.

**Execution.** Consider any $a,b \in (0,1)$ such that $a+b=1.$ Since the domain of $f$ was assumed convex, we know that $f(ax+by)$ is well-defined. Since $x$ and $y$ are distinct, we know by strict convexity that:

$$f(ax+by) < af(x)+bf(y)$$

Now clearly, $f(x)=f(y),$ since $x$ and $y$ are in the minimizer of $f$. So:

$$f(ax+by) < af(x)+bf(y) = af(x)+bf(x) = (a+b)f(x) = f(x)$$

Hence $f(ax+by)<f(x).$ But this contradicts that $x$ is in the minimizer of $f$, completing the proof.

**Addendum.** Okay, I was also able to come up with the following:

**Definition 1.** Suppose $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function.

- By the *local minimizer* of $f$, I mean the set of all $x \in X$ such that for some neighbourhood $N$ of $x,$ every $x' \in N$ satisfies $f(x) \leq f(x').$
- By the **strict** local minimizer of $f$, I mean the set of all $x \in X$ such that for some neighbourhood $N$ of $x,$ every $y \in N \setminus \{x\}$ satisfies $f(x) < f(x').$

> **Proposition 1.** Suppose $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex, where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set. Then the strict local minimizer of $f$ has at most one element.

*Proof.* Suppose $x$ and $y$ are elements of the strict local minimizer of $f$. I claim that $x=y$.

Suppose for a contradiction that $x \neq y$.

Since $x$ and $y$ are in the strict local minimizer, they're certainly in the (non-strict) local minimizer; hence by convexity, they're in the (global) minimizer. So $f(x)=f(y)$.

Now since $x$ is in the strict local minimizer, there is a neighbourhood $N$ of $x$ such that $f(x) < f(x')$ for all $x' \in N \setminus \{x\}$. Let $r\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ satisfy $B_r(x) \subseteq N$.

We're going to find an element in $B_r(x) \setminus \{x\}$ that is no higher than $x$. Recall that $f(x)=f(y)$. Hence by convexity, for all $a,b \in [0,1]$ satisfying $a+b=1$, we have

$$(*) \qquad f(ax+by) \leq f(x)$$

We now have to play the following game: find $a,b \in [0,1]$ such that $ax+by \in B_r(x) \setminus \{x\}$. Our instincts suggest that we should consider $a=r$ and $b=1-r$. This doesn't quite work, of course; we need to somehow scale by the distance between $x$ and $y$. If $x$ and $y$ are very distant, then $a$ needs to be much smaller. So consider:

$$a = \frac{r}{d(y,x)}, \qquad b = 1-\frac{r}{d(y,x)}$$

Since $r$ is non-zero, hence $a$ is non-zero, so $ax+by$ is indeed distinct from $x$. It remains to show that $ax+by \in B_r(x).$ In other words, we're trying to:

**Show:** $\|(ax+by)-x\| < r$

We have: $$\|(ax+by)-x\| = \|(a-1)x+by\| = \|\left(\frac{r}{d(y,x)}-1\right) x+\left(1-\frac{r}{d(y,x)}\right)y\|$$

$$=\left|\left(\frac{r}{d(y,x)}-1\right)\right| \cdot \|x-y\| = |r-d(y,x)|<r$$

This basically completes the proof: it follows that $ax+by \in B_r(x) \setminus \{x\}$, hence $ax+by \in N$, hence $f(x)<f(ax+by)$. But by $(*)$, we have $f(ax+by) \leq f(x)$, a contradiction.

Comment: I think a little revision could make the answer better. $y$ and $x$ are confusing to be minimizers because $y$ are already used for some other points on the set $X$. May be one could replace all $y$ and $x$ with $x_0$ and $x_1$ after the *proof*.

Comment: ohh bon apetit. wanna that I prepare ur food too?=)

Answer (score 4):

Strict convexity is by no means the only sufficient condition. Others (below, we use $x^*$ to denote a local minimum):

- $f(x)$ is a *norm*: then by definition, $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$, and $f(x)=0$ implies $x=0$. The absolute value function is a simple example here.
- *Local* strict convexity. That is, $f(x)$ is strictly convex in a small neighborhood $(x^*-\delta,x^*+\delta)$. The Huber penalty function is an example of a function that is locally, but not globally, strictly convex.

You can construct others; for instance, $\|Ax-b\|$, where $A$ has full column rank will have a single local minimum, but it is not strictly convex for all $(A,b)$. (I think it is if $b\not\in\mathop{\textrm{Range}}(A))$.

Comment: thx. interesting points. very careful answerer=)

Comment: ;-) I actually had to walk back my answer a bit from its original. I think a subgradient condition is possible, so if I figure it out I will edit.