# Two fundamental questions about convexity of a function (number2)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

The second question is as follows (the first one is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207421/two-fundamental-questions-about-convexity-of-a-function)):

> Consider a function of two variables $f(x,y)$ on some compact domain. Let it be convex in $x$ and concave in $y$. Is it true that $f(x,y)$ has a uniqe saddle point (stationary point)? Is $(\hat x,\hat y)=\arg \min_x\max_y f(x,y)$, the argument of saddle point, unique?
>   Is there any role of being strictly concave (or convex) in this case?

My guess is that $f(x,y)$ owns a unique saddle point because of the convexity and concavity of the function. I also guess that if the function is strictly concave-convex, then, the argument of the saddle point is also unique.

Comment: No. Consider $f(x,y) = \max\{|x|,1\}-\max\{|y|,1\}$. I *think* that strict convexity in $x$ and strict concavity in $y$ will help, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelGrant it is really a basic question and I couldnt find anything about it in internet..

Comment: I don't have a lot to offer on saddle point problems I am afraid.

Comment: Thats fine. What I know from Von Neuman is that min max=max min and this indicates a saddle point. If there is then a saddle point then it is written as $f(\hat x,y)\leq f(\hat x,\hat y)\leq f(x,\hat y)$. This says in my opinion that there exists a unique saddle value BUT  I cannot say $100\%$ that the argument is also unique.

Comment: True, in my example, the saddle point value is unique, but not the arguments.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer now both questions are closed and both have no answers. I mentioned in mathoverflow that it was asked in mathstackexchange.

Comment: That's not right. I will go ahead and flag the older post for moderator attention. Hopefully they will reopen it￼

Comment: @MichaelGrant thanks for your spiritual support. Will you lend me your chicken to love for some time too?=)

Comment: Actually, the other one (migrated from mathoverflow) still looks open.

Comment: Now it is okay. Seems good as you said. thx again.

Comment: @MichaelGrant you said that in your example that the saddle value was unique. which point is that? I cannot use the method of partial derivatives. Could you please let me know how we get the point in this case?thx.